# Extensionless url rewriting / filtering url rewrites

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I've done some url rewriting, always using the Intelligencia.UrlRewriter and it always worked fine. But now i want to achieve the following and somehow i can't get it right.

i want:

www.mydomain.com/products/books > rewrite to www.mydomain.com/products.aspx?id=books
this works fine, because i can set my criteria to /products/..

www.mydomain.com/mybook > rewrite to www.mydomain.com/productdetails.aspx?id=mybook
and of course i want www.mydomain.com/newbooks.aspx to function normally
and these last 2 don't work together.

is there a way i can tell my rewrite rule to only rewrite when there is no extension in my url? or is there an other trick?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought i'd solve this old, unanswered question. The problem with the extensionless urls turned out to be some configuration problem in IIS. Our system admin fixed this by allowing these urls and after that the rewriter had no problems picking up and translating the URLS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit off the road, but try using ASP.NET Routing instead of URL Rewriter.
I was playing (and messing up) with the rewriter, and here on Stackoverflow I was advised to use Routing, and it is MUCH better (and easier when you get it).
You'll need some little changes to your ASPX files though, but very small.

Comment: I've looked in to this Routing a bit, and must say that it looks pretty cool! It doesn't really fit the old project i was talking about in this post, but for a new project i'm doing it seems like the perfect solution!